# Checking AWS S3 write permissions in Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, boto3

In Boto3, I can write to a bucket with [`put_object`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object). This could fail due to path-wise permissions issues. I want to check if I have write permissions without actually writing data to a particular S3 path.

Answer (score 1):

You can [Test IAM Policies with the IAM Policy Simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html#policies-simulator-using-api), which is also accessible via API.

Boto3 has [`simulate_principal_policy()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.simulate_principal_policy):

> Simulate how a set of IAM policies attached to an IAM entity works with a list of API operations and AWS resources to determine the policies' effective permissions. The entity can be an IAM user, group, or role. If you specify a user, then the simulation also includes all of the policies that are attached to groups that the user belongs to.

Comment: How can I use this to do a dry run put_object? It looks like I need to specify a policy ARN. I just want to try a dry run from whatever identity I am currently using.

Comment: It says "The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of a user, group, or role whose policies you want to include in the simulation." So, put in the ARN of your IAM User or whatever identity you are currently using.

Comment: Alas, the simulator itself requires permissions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html#permissions-required_policy-simulator